# How to get SQL combined field result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table "student" in my database;

```
CREATE TABLE student 
(
stud_id VARCHAR(20),
fname VARCHAR(100),
lname VARCHAR(100),
PRIMARY KEY (stud_id)
);
```

I have data in "student" table

```
INSERT INTO student (stud_id, fname, lname)
VALUES ('s0001', 'foo', 'bar');
```

I want to find `stud_id` of the student who has the full name "foo bar"
how to do this?
I tried this

```
SELECT stud_id FROM student WHERE 'fname'+' '+'lname' LIKE 'fo%';
```

Its not error but i cant get "foo bar" stud_id.
How to do this?

Comment: mysql concatenation uses [`concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) function ( not + )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes will make your column as string so avoid using it in columns. Also instead of `+` use `concat` function to concatenate the columns

```
SELECT stud_id 
FROM student 
WHERE concat(fname,' ',lname) LIKE 'fo%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT stud_id FROM student WHERE Convert(varchar(150),fname+' '+lname) LIKE 'fo%';
```

Comment: offering some explanation to your answer will make it better.